# When to use password_needs_rehash

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I'm confused on when and how to use password_needs_rehash. I'll walk you through my thought process.

I have hashed and stored my users passwords into a users database using password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT). I then allow users to login and at some point in the process, my controller calls password_verify($password, $hashedPassword), which verifies my user. I'm assuming that this function hashes the given password based on the algorithm used in the hashed password.

Here's my real question: If the default algorithm changes, when do I call the password_needs_rehash() function? do I call it from my controller after the user logs in, but before the user is redirected to the dashboard?

Comment: Thanks! I had a logic error in my controller, so the password_needs_rehash was never called. Turns out I was doing it right all along, I just broke my controller when I tried to implement it. It all works now, thanks!

Comment: Well, call it whenever the user provides you with a password. Making it a silent step in the login process would be a good idea; that way it will be done without you having to think about it.